# How is using JWT refresh tokens and short lived access tokens not massively insecure?

Tags: security, jwt

As I understand it, the typical (and simplified) usage of JWT refresh tokens is as follows:

1. User logs into the system. User is granted a refresh token and a short lived (e.g: 10 minute expiry) access token. The refresh token is stored in the database of the "authentication server" for revocation purposes. Any requests made to the app ("resource server") will use the short lived access token.
2. When the user's 10 minutes are up, the client will send a request to the auth server for a new access token using the refresh token.
3. When the user changes their password or revokes access to a specific signin (in the case of theft, a lost device, etc), the refresh token is removed from the auth server database and rendered invalid.

Thus, when a user accidentally leaks his password out or loses his device, he can simply change his password, which would cause all previously issued refresh tokens to become invalidated.

However, the obvious security hole here is that the short lived access token is still perfectly valid for the next 10 minutes. And 10 minutes, no matter how short a time, is still plenty of time for a malicious user to cause some damage.

The only possible solutions I can think of are to:

- maintain a blacklist or whitelist of access tokens. This makes the
  usage of refresh tokens seem pretty redundant. If we're going to hit
  the database on every request or to keep a cached list of blacklisted
  access tokens, then what's the point of having a refresh token?
- make the expiry of the access token shorter (e.g: every 1 minute
  instead of every 10 minute). This doesn't solve the problem perse, it
  just does some damage control, since it shortens the window of time a
  malicious user has to do damage. And hitting the database for a new
  access token every minute doesn't seem much better than hitting the
  database on every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working on the exact same problem.  Although I cannot say I am any sort of definitive authority on the subject, I'm glad to share what I came up with based on a lot of research and building out a proof of concept.

The requirement is to have instant token access token revocation.  During regular operation of the application, the actual probability of the scenario of a malicious user gaining access to someone's account is relatively low.  This is not to say it should not be accounted for, but it's not going to be the case for 99.9% of request that come into your system, thus having it check the access token against the database on all the requests where it doesn't matter is bad design in my opinion.

However, bad design or not, it doesn't change the requirement.  Requiring the access token to be refreshed every minute does not seem to be much better as it would put tremendous strain on the auth server and database.  Managing an in memory access token revocation list wouldn't do much good because it wouldn't be shared across instances. Depending on your volume of users this may be able to get a way with using a database for while, but I don't think it would scale beyond a certain point.

The solution I chose to go with is using a shared in memory database/cache.  I've evaluated Cassandra, Redis, and Apache Ignite and for the time being, decided to use Ignite.  Because I am not sure how it will perform once this goes to production, I've made the components easily swappable for another in memory solution in case the performance is not sufficient.

I have a JWT filter responsible for validating each request, at the end of which I make a call to the shared cache to check a access token revocation list.  I anticipate the list will be empty the vast majority of the time.  To further reduce potential performance degradation, I hash to tokens to about 40 characters using MD5 before revoking them.  This capability allows me to have an hour long access token life and a refresh token with an 18 hour life without worry that I won't be able to remove a malicious user if the need should arise.

Personally, I don't see a way around keeping track of some user state on the backend.  The trick is to do it in such a way that you can still easily add instances of your backend to scale your application.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but if I'm understanding this right, you'd essentially be replicating your in memory database/cache across all application servers that require access to it? I've never really used in memory databases like Redis, but I'm going to guess that they come out-of-the-box with the ability to easily sync between different instances of themselves?

Comment: Redis and other in memory providers are different than the programming paradigm I'm used to.  Out of the box each instance knows how to communicate with each other, but they need to be configured to do so.  That being said, they're well supported and not to difficult to figure out in my opinion.  Most come with library's that show you how to interact with them.  Redis has at least a few tutorials on how to secure them in production.

Comment: You can also mix approaches.
On a less sensitive request, you could rely on the info presented in the (possibly revoked) AccessToken. On sensitive requests (e.g. change my login info), you check with the auth server if the presented token is actually valid. If your application normally sees few highly sensitive requests and many less sensitive requests, this can be a good compromise between security and performance.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of JWT tokens is that they are self-contained and live on their own for a short while. If that does not suit your requirements you can revert to another type of access token, namely an opaque one that requires so-called introspection at the Authorization Server (AS). You are right that (if the results of that call are not cached) that call will hit the AS every time and partly defeat the purpose of the refresh token but on the other hand, actively having to revoke cached access token results from each Resource Server that has done an introspection call will result in a management and overhead nightmare.

There's no silver bullet. You will have to choose the access token type, expiry and cache duration that matches your situation an security requirements best.